# Object Cloning Vs Serialization

Tags: php, serialization, clone

My goal is to restart InnoDB transaction the right way if Deadlock found, and sometimes, data in an object changes upon execution and I need to roll it back to its former state. For that I might use Object Cloning, but I'm not %100 sure about it, because these objects have no `__clone()` methods defined and I have no time to add them. From the other side, it's very rare these Objects have composed Objects inside.

Here is my code:

```
protected function callAction() {

    $action = $this->Method.'Action';

    // Storing an Object
    $SavedPackageObject = clone $this->PackageObject;

    try {

        // First attempt
        $res = $this->PackageObject->$action();

    } catch(MySQLiDeadlockException $e) {

        $i = 0;

        do {

            // Restoring an Object
            $this->PackageObject = clone $SavedPackageObject;

            try {

                $res = $this->PackageObject->$action();

                // Success    
                break;

            } catch(MySQLiDeadlockException $e) {

                // Cancel iterations if limit is reached
                if($i > 9)
                    throw $e;

                usleep(100000);

                $i++;

            }

        } while(1);

    }

    return $res;

}
```

There's another approach on Object copying which is Deep Cloning:

```
unserialize(serialize($Object));
```

I also thinking of adding `__clone()` to parent class of all of these package Objects:

```
// php.net example
function __clone(){ 
    foreach($this as $name => $value){ 
        if(gettype($value)=='object'){ 
            $this->$name= clone($this->$name); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

**Question:** Is it okay to use `clone` and define `__clone()` in parent or I could just serialize/unserialize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you're doing, `clone` makes the most sense and should be the most efficient. I can't think of any benefit of serializing your object to a string, just to unserialize it to regain it's state.

I'd assume that if you had to override `_clone`, you'd have to override `_sleep` and `__wakeup` (depending on your object) if serializing?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I have added __clone() to parent and it works as a charm.